# SIGILL fault when running program

Tags: android, android-ndk, tombstone

New one to me for errors signal 4 SIGILL.  When I take a look at the tombstone file and type int he address I get ?? i.e.

Here is someof the tombstone:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:2.2/FRF91/43546:eng/test-keys'
pid: 2083, tid: 2089  >>> com.activities <<<
signal 4 (SIGILL), fault addr 00016b10
 r0 00000006  r1 8086caa4  r2 8086fbcf  r3 0006b60b
 r4 80887fc4  r5 0006b60b  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
 r8 80813b00  r9 4e23a038  10 00000019  fp 0011d230
 ip 808880f8  sp 47bcbca8  lr 8083a8d1  pc 00016b10  cpsr 20000010
         #00  pc 00016b10  [heap]
         #01  pc 0003a8ce  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #02  pc 0003d02c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #03  pc 0001890c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #04  pc 0001e8c4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #05  pc 0001d790  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #06  pc 0005408e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #07  pc 0005bde2  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #08  pc 00018714  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #09  pc 0001e8c4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #10  pc 0001d790  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #11  pc 00053eec  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #12  pc 00054102  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #13  pc 0004825a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #14  pc 0001103c  /system/lib/libc.so
         #15  pc 00010b20  /system/lib/libc.so
```

I go my android-ndk-r7\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3\prebuilt\windows\bin directory using command window, type in this command and get no function at all.

```
arm-linux-androideabi--addr2line.exe -C -f -e libdvm.so 0003a8ce
```

and it returns

```
??
??:0
```

I seem to remember this working before...and yes I have the libdvm.so in the same working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well apparently this occurs only when I test it on the 2.2 emulator.  On a myTouch 3G phone the code never crashes.  Must be a pointer memory issue or not enough RAM allocated for simulator.